# Access VBA use variable to refer to field on form

Tags: forms, vba, variables, ms-access

I have a 2 variables, 1 referencing the current form and 1 referencing a table. I want to be able to use these variables to show a msgbox with the value of the current form field that the variable from the table is referencing.
Here is what I have so far:

```
strfrmname = Screen.ActiveForm.Name

strheader2 = DLookup("DataOut2", "dbo_lookups", "Type = 'ChangeLogging' AND DataIn = '" _
& strfrmname & "'")

strheader3 = Forms(strFormName).Controls(strheader2)

MsgBox strheader3
```

This gives me the runtime error 2465 "cant find the field 'Field1' referred to in your expression.

When I change the "strheader3 =" line to the below it works though?

```
strheader3 = Forms!Frm_LabelAmendView.Controls(strheader2)
```

Please can someone help me get this working using variables for both the form and the control?

Anything questions please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a typo in your post?  You have `strfrmname` in one place and `strFormName` in another place.

Comment: haha, yes I do, I noticed that as soon as I posted the question! That was the problem! Thanks!!!

Comment: @user2294977 : So, is that figured out the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable names are wrong.  You're referencing it as both strfrmname and strFormName.  Choose one or the other and it should work fine.